JPQL update query how to define joins getting getting exception
I have a use case of using joins to update the values in one table along with having a check to check the alertType which is in another table for which I have to use the join b/w two tables.
Query -
    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query("""
    UPDATE ItemAlert ia
    SET ia.alertCount = ia.alertCount + 1
    WHERE ia.alertId = :alertId
    AND ia.podId = :podId
    AND ia.alertHeader.alertType = :alertType
    """)
    void updateAlertCount(@Param("alertId") Integer alertId,
                          @Param("alertType") AlertType alertType,
                          @Param("podId") Integer podId);

Error -
org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: Entity join did not specify a predicate, please define an on clause or use an explicit cross join:

Also If I go with traditional method of using from table t inner
join table t This approach doesn't work in JPQL. But while using the
join in Select query this works why?

Tried all possible ways not getting any resolution to this.
Note:- attribute alertId is there in both tables but there is no direct mapping between tables.

You don't need and you can not use join for that. JPQL is not a mag, it executed sql statements in the end. Sql update statement does not suppose using joins. See https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp Instead do update and check in separate statements but in one transaction. If check fails rollback transaction.
